# What is a binary fuse filter?

Tags: data-structures, xor, bloom-filter

There was a great post about XOR filters a while back: [What is an XOR filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527507/what-is-an-xor-filter)

Can someone provide an explanation about the binary fuse filter? How does it differ in construction and what are the reasonings for such choices? I tried to read the paper but got lost in the binary fuse specific details. How does it compare to XOR? Why is it smaller and faster?

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a (preferably free) link to the binary fuse filter paper?

Comment: Yes, here you go: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.01174.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intuitively, a binary fuse filter follows the same strategy as a regular XOR filter but with a slightly different strategy for placing items, so if you haven’t yet read about [how XOR filters work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527507/what-is-an-xor-filter), it’s best to start there.

Like an XOR filter, the binary fuse filter (and several other related structures like the Ribbon filter) work by computing a fingerprint f(x) for each item x, as well as computing some hashes h1(x), h2(x), and h3(x) that give positions into an array. The array is then populated so that the value h1(x) xor h2(x) xor h3(x) = f(x) for all elements in the filter.

The difference between XOR filters and binary fuse filters is how that table is populated. Both data structures use an approach called ***peeling*** to fill in the table. That’s the strategy outlined in the other post: find a slot that has only one item hashing to it, remove it, recursively place the other elements, then set the value in that slot so that the removed element’s hashes work out correctly.

In an XOR filter, the array of slots needs to have size roughly 1.23n for this process to have a high chance of succeeding. The reason for this is surprisingly mathematically deep: if the hashes are uniformly distributed across the table, then with fewer than 1.23n slots the probability that the peeling strategy works drops very quickly to 0, and with more than 1.23n slots the probability that the peeling strategy works very rapidly trends to 1. Therefore, you can think of 1.23n as a hard theoretical limit on the size of the table using an XOR filter.

The idea behind a fuse filter is to change how hashes are assigned over the table. Rather than having the hashes chosen so that they’re uniformly random across the table, we use another approach. Pick a ***window size*** w. Then, for each element x, choose h1(x), h2(x), and h3(x) in the following way:

1. Select a random window of size w within the array.
2. Choose h1(x), h2(x), and h3(x) uniformly at random within that window.

(The actual logic of the binary fuse filter is slightly different than this in that it requires h1(x), h2(x), and h3(x) to be spaced out a bit, but let’s ignore that for now.)

Once we’ve assigned hashes this way, we use the same peeling strategy as before to fill in the array: we find a slot where only one item hashes, remove that item, place all the other items, then put the item back in.

What’s beautiful here is how that peeling proceeds. Intuitively, because of how we assigned hashes, the slots closest to the two ends of the array are the ones most likely to only have one item hash to them. Why? Because the only way you can have collisions near the ends is if you have two items whose windows are both very close to the ends and that happen to pick slots within those windows that are far to the sides of the windows. That’s pretty unlikely, and as a result the leftmost and rightmost items are likely to be peeled.

But once those items are peeled, by the same logic, the items that are now on the far left or far right are likely to be peelable. This is where the name “fuse” comes from - it’s like lighting a fuse at both ends and watching it burn in toward the center.

The fact that there’s some predictability here about where items will be peelable means that we need fewer table slots than if the hashes were assigned randomly across the table. The paper cites a space usage of around 1.13n table slots needed, a big improvement over the 1.23n needed for an XOR filter, and it’s done purely by changing the strategy for assigning hashes. Pretty neat!